# summaryType function to have sum of a float number

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I'm trying to use summaryType to make an addition of all my float number I don't know really what I have to put in this function to make an addition of all my record[name] someone can help me ?

```
summaryType: function (val, name, record) {
// ??
}
```

My `record[name]` return a float number like this: 0.015962702 or 0.005360679  I just want a totaly of each number :) and after I will multiplicate by 100 to have a percent value :)

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
summaryType: function (val, name, record) {
    // return val for next calculation
    return parseFloat(val || 0.0) + parseFloat(record[name] * 100);
}
```